# Plotting over multiple lengths and columns

Tags: r, plot

I am wanting to plot on the X axis 17K sets of intervals, where I plot the start and stop intervals for each Chr column. However, these intervals are not plotting correctly to each chr? This I figured out from how the plot was running off the right side and the red dots did not match up with input data. Thoughts on a fix? To be clear chr.len is the length of each chromosome.

```
Data;
ID  Chr Start   Stop
XLOC_007681 2R  11896162    11896597
XLOC_024365 3R  11283380    11286479
XLOC_021494 3R  16392979    16396291
XLOC_012125 3L  136830  138533
XLOC_031405 X   8002493 8004054
XLOC_014371 3L  15537489    15538755
XLOC_005808 2L  20704834    20706685
XLOC_005809 2L  20706861    20708183
XLOC_005807 2L  20703325    20703897
```

## ============================================================

```
chr.len <- c(22422827, 204112, 347038, 23011544, 368872, 21146708, 3288731, 24543557, 2555491, 27905053, 2517507, 1351857, 10049037)
names(chr.len) <- c("X", "XHet", "YHet", "2L", "2LHet", "2R", "2RHet", "3L", "3LHet", "3R", "3RHet", "4", "U")
chr.gap <- 2000000
chr.cum <- cumsum(c(0, chr.len[1:12])) + (0:12)*chr.gap
names(chr.cum) <- names(chr.len)
# ============================================================
png(file = "C:/Users/cahighfi/Desktop/XLOC_Position.png", width = 10, height = 5, units = "in", res = 300)
plot(c(0, chr.cum["U"] + chr.len["U"]), c(0, 1), type = "n", axes = FALSE, ylab = "", xlab = "", )
segments(XLOC.pos$Start + chr.cum[XLOC.pos$Chr], 0.5, XLOC.pos$Stop + chr.cum[XLOC.pos$Chr], 0.5, lwd = 10)
segments(DrugXLOC.pos$Start + chr.cum[DrugXLOC.pos$Chr], 0.5, DrugXLOC.pos$Stop + chr.cum[DrugXLOC.pos$Chr], 0.5, lwd = 10, col = c("red"))
axis(side = 1, at = chr.cum + chr.len/2, labels = parse(text = paste("italic(\"", names(chr.len), "\")", sep = "")), mgp = c(2.5, 0.5, 0), tck = -0.015, cex.axis = 1.0)
dev.off()
```

[Output plot][[1]]

[[1]]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPObX.png

Comment: Hi Dan,chr.len is the length of each chromosome I am plotting to

Comment: DanY, the problem is not the Xlim arg. the major issue is the intervals are not plotting correclty - to the chr -

Comment: What wasnt clear? It is laid out in text